# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Tags: json, api, ionic-framework

I am working on an Ionic app . I am stuck with is error .  l want to get data json api earthquake form  [USGS](https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_hour.geojson) then set coordinates on google map . Returning json data in console log is good but l have error when I run my app `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0`

my full code

```
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
  protected points: { lng: number, lat: number }[] = [];

  items: any
  pet: string = "Today";
  map: GoogleMap;
  mags: number;

  constructor(
    private http: HTTP) {

  }

  async ngOnInit() {

    this.getData()

  }

  async getData() {

   this.http.get(`https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_hour.geojson`, {}, {}).then(data => {

      this.items = JSON.parse(data.data)

      console.log(this.items)


      for (let datas of JSON.parse(data.data)['features']) {

        this.points.push({ lng: datas.geometry.coordinates[0], lat: datas.geometry.coordinates[1] });

        let dest = this.points.map((coords) => {
          return this.map.addMarkerSync({
            position: coords,
          });
        });


        this.map = GoogleMaps.create('map_canvas');
      }

    })
  }

}
```

short json response

```
{
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          35.9752,
          36.2659,
          10
        ]
      },
      "id": "us700036mi"
    }
  ]
}
```

any idea please ?

Answer (score 0):

l adjusted  my code again and he is working fine , even he shows coordinates on google map

```
      async getData() {

    this.http.get(`https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&minlatitude=28.071980&minlongitude=35.683594&maxlatitude=38.203655&maxlongitude=51.108398`, {}, {}).then(data => {

      this.items = JSON.parse(data.data)
      let earth = JSON.parse(data.data)

      console.log(this.items)

    let mapOptions: GoogleMapOptions = {
      camera: {
         target: this.points,

       }
    };
    this.map = GoogleMaps.create('map_canvas',mapOptions);

      for (let datas of earth['features']) {

        this.points.push({ lng: datas.geometry.coordinates[0], lat: datas.geometry.coordinates[1] });

        let dest = this.points.map((coords) => {
          return this.map.addMarkerSync({
            position: coords,

          });
        });


      }



    })
  }
```